# enable flickr and picasa in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce, flickr, picasa

My client needs flickr and picasa support in my TinyMCE editor. Has anybody got any advice on plugins which would allow him to do 'standard' embed functions? I know that wordpress supports this, and I'd like to enable it in my own non-wordpress TinyMCE editor in a similar way.

Also, I'm using HTMLPurifier on the server to sanitise any input. I've enabled safe iframe embedding, so can support that, but other types of embed may need some extra work on HTMLPurifier.

What are the standard ways of embedding Picasa and Flickr, and does anybody know of any good TinyMCE plugins that support it?

Thanks.

Comment: it might be possible to get the wordpress tinymce plugin for picasa and use it in your context. you should check the wordpress source code for that plugin (usually its lovcated in tinymce/plugins)

Answer (score 0):

I found the tinymce picasa plugin. It is located [here](http://code.google.com/p/picasa-plugin-tinymce/downloads/list).
You need to copy that folder to tinymces plugin directory. Your tinymce configuration needs to be modified so that that plugin gets added and the button too.

Concerning flickr [this](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=11892) might be of interest to you.

Comment: Thank you for both of those. Looking at the picassa one now. RE the Flickr plugin, it doesn't look like it is available for download unless I'm going crazy? Has anybody spotted the download link for this plugin?

Comment: you can use firebug to get the js source

Comment: RE: the picasa plugin, I can't find any docs. I've installed the plugin directory, and added picasa_image to my tinymce config. I get a picasa button, but the dialoge just gives me a browse field to search my local HDD. I'm not quite sure what I'm supposed to do with it...

Comment: well, i did not check this plugin out myself - sry

Comment: Hi Thariama, thank you very much for your input. I'm still a little stumped though because the picasa plugin has no docs, and 'steeling' the flickr one from firebug will be a little bit of a mission, it doesn't look like it is fully browser compatible, and also I'm not sure about the ethics of taking it without it being available for download. Can anybody else help?