# wordpress tinymce on non wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I need to emulate the wordpress tinymce with some of the plugins on a non-wordpress site. Is this likely to be possible?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. TinyMCE is independent from Wordpress, so yes, you can install it on a non-Wordpress site

Comment: it depends on the plugins you wnat to integrate in the non-wordpress tinymce. if wordpress plugions need a wordpress environment it might be impossible to tweak it to make it functional

Comment: Hi Thariama, Thanks again see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476810/enable-flickr-and-picasa-in-tinymce. I have TinyMCE working, but need picasa and flickr support "as on wordpress" (quote from my client). This is a non-wordpress site. There are wordpress plugins like this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ultimate-tinymce/ which add functionality to tinymce, but I would hope to use them outside of wordpress. I can't find the right plugins for tinymce, so am wondering how wordpress have done it, and if the plugins that they use are available for my non-wordpress instance of tinymce.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. The tinymce editor is here: https://www.tinymce.com/
Plugins for tinymce are here: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/